# SQLITE3: Error while updating the database

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

```
def update_data():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('address_book.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    record_id= delete_box.get()
    c.execute("""UPDATE addresses SET
        first_name = :first,
        last_name = :last,       
        address = :address,
        city = :city,
        state = :state,
        zipcode = :zipcode
        WHERE oid=:oid """,
        {
        'first':f_name_editor.get(),
        'last':l_name_editor.get(),
        'city':city_editor.get(),
        'state':state_editor.get(),
        'zipcode':zipcode_editor.get(),
        'oid':record_id


        })
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

I am getting the follow error when I try to update the database:
***c.execute("""UPDATE addresses SET
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: You did not supply a value for binding 3.***

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what is wrong. "binding 3" refers to the address. You haven't provided an address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't you miss the `address` binding ?

> **You did not supply a value for binding 3.**